# Why coord_equal doesn't work the way it should?

Tags: r, ggplot2

According to this [reference page](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_equal.html) on ggplot2, the following command should give an equal aspect ratio (1:1) of x and y.

```
qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + coord_equal(ratio = 1)
```

However, as I type it and I am seeing this. 
[image]

Does anyone know what's the problem?

Edit:

Without `+coord_equal()` however, I can obtain a 1:1 aspect ratio. However, as soon as I add legend on the right, the 1:1 aspect gets changed. The suggestions provided are simply too cumbersome to achieve desired effect. As suggested, I've filed a ticket to github/ggplot2.

Comment: What your `coord_equal(ratio = 1)` does is make sure that the an equal length on both axis represents the same change in units.  So 1cm = 5units for both axis.  Since the x axis is more variable it will be scrunched like that.

Comment: Also the 1cm = 5units wasn't literal.  I don't know how many units a cm would be on your graph - but I do know that the same length would represent the same number of units for both the x and y axis.

Comment: @Oliver, your question is completely justified. The behavior of ggplot2 is not the one described on the official page. The plot on the [help page](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_equal.html) about `coord_equal` displays a graphic in which the relative range of both axes is identical if `ratio = 1`.

Comment: @Sven I agree that the question is justified - but I thought it should be pointed out what the actual behavior is.

Comment: @Oliver I would recommend you create a ticket at https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues. This way hadley can fix the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Might as well turn my comment into an answer.

What your `coord_equal(ratio = 1)` does is make sure that the an equal length on both axis represents the same change in units. So 1cm = 5units for both axis (for example - that conversion rate probably isn't correct but the idea is the same). Since the x axis is more variable it will be scrunched like that.  You can add a ylim parameter to `coord_equal` if you want the y-axis to be more stretched out.

Comment: I can manually calculate the relative ration of y/x to adjust the aspect. However, the question is, why the same dataset, same command, same library version if I am not mistaken, the reference page display a a perfect square ... diff from mine.

Comment: are you sure the library version is actually the same? ggplot has been under rapid development recently. `news(grepl("coord_equal",Text),package="ggplot2")` didn't show anything, but maybe there was an inadvertent change ...

Answer (score 5):

After github/ggplot2 ticket filing. Winston helped me to find a succinct solution:

```
qplot(mpg,wt,data=mtcars, shape="carb") + theme(aspect.ratio=1)
```

Also, there appears to be some behavioral changes between ggplot2 0.8 to 0.9, the original documentation is probably out of date.

Answer (score 2):

To get a plot similar to the one on the [reference page](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_equal.html), the limits of the y-axis have to be changed manually:

```
library(ggplot2)

r_wt <- range(with(mtcars, wt))
r_mpg <- range(with(mtcars, mpg))
cent <- mean(r_wt)
ylimits <- cent + c(-1, +1) * diff(r_mpg)/2

qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars) + coord_cartesian(ylim = ylimits)
```

[image]

Comment: You should still use `coord_equal(ratio = 1, ylim = ylim)` though.  Otherwise you're not really doing the same thing.  For example in the image you posted the x scale and y scale don't match perfectly (5 units in the y direction is slightly longer on the physical graph than 5 units in the x direction).